# Are there any examples of mother having priority over father?

Tags: women, priorities, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

Are there any cases in which mother takes precedence over father?

Comment: Welcome (back?) Leonot. Yes there is, I have not time to work at this today. I hope that erudite people will convincing you that Torah loves mothers.

Comment: Leonor, please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. Otherwise your questions don't show under your same account. You can then ask to merge both accounts

Comment: Also, since you now have two accounts, be sure to check the [answers given to your first question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69433/why-prefer-the-father-to-the-mother)

Comment: The obvious one is that Jewish religion follows after the mother, not the father. To understand the ways Jews are commanded to relate to their father and mother, see https://www.ou.org/torah/parsha/rabbi-fox-on-parsha/parshat_vaetchanan_honoring_parents/

Comment: A person is required to support his mother before his father - anyone have that source?

Answer (score 3):

[Leviticus 19:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/x/x0319.htm):

> איש אמו ואביו תיראו, ואת-שבתתי תשמרו:  אני, יהוה אלהיכם.
>
> Every man must **revere his mother** and father, and keep My Sabbaths.
>   I am Hashem your Lord.

The Talmud in [Kidushin 30b](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%9C_%D7%91) - [31a](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%90) explains this precedence:

> תניא רבי אומר גלוי וידוע לפני מי שאמר והיה העולם שבן מכבד את אמו יותר
>   מאביו מפני שמשדלתו בדברים לפיכך הקדים הקב"ה כיבוד אב לכיבוד אם  וגלוי
>   וידוע לפני מי שאמר והיה העולם שהבן מתיירא מאביו יותר מאמו מפני שמלמדו
>   תורה לפיכך הקדים הקב"ה מורא האם למורא האב
>
> Rebi said: Hashem knows that a child honors his mother more than his father
>   because she sways him (with pleasant words), therefore, He commanded to
>   honor the father before the mother (Shemos 20:12)); Hashem knows that a child revere
>   his father more than his mother because his father teaches him Torah.
>   Therefore, He commanded to revere the mother before the father.

Comment: where do we see anything about the mother having priority? We just see that the Torah had to put more emphasis on something since it might be disregarded. In an actual conflict between serving the father and mother, there is no indication that the mother would take priority.

Comment: I don't think you understand the answer or you're ignoring the second source, it speaks for itself. Both of the cases does not justify the downvote.

Comment: If indeed I misunderstood the answer, then others likely will as well. Consider therefore clarifying it.

Answer (score -1):

Since a wife is commanded to honor her husband a Father takes precedence.

When they are not married a Father would seemingly take precedence on account of his Torah knowledge (since it is a man who is commanded in Torah study, even when the woman also has Torah stidy, and the fulfilment of one who is commandes is greater).

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Ben. I don't see how this answers the question which was cases that the _mother_ takes precedence.

Comment: Please expand your answer to either give cases where the mother takes precedence or give sources to explain why it would never happen.